# Chrome extension: How to settimeout with update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I newbie in chrome extension and I need help in this case, I have a problem where `setTimeout`is not working properly it is running crazy like this
15 sec,10 sec,1 sec,1 sec,1 sec ...
I tried also to use `setInterval`  but I got same issue

```
chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener(info => {
if (!info.frameId && (info.error === 'net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED' || 'net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED')) {
console.log(info)
setTimeout(timeoutTrigger(info),15000)
}
});
function timeoutTrigger(info)
{
chrome.tabs.update(info.tabId, {url: info.url});
}
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout(timeoutTrigger, 15000, info)`

Comment: @wOxxOm Unfortunately the problem still persists, it's running insanely fast and crazy

Comment: You probably didn't reload the extension.

Comment: I was deleted old one and add new one with your suggest if your tab got error network the extension will start after 15 sec 14 sec 10 sec 1 sec 1 sec to reach speed < 1 second and crash the browser

Comment: You have another mistake: `||` should be `|| info.error === `

Comment: Thank you very much it's fixed by using ` || info.error ===`